# How to grab text input from textbox and open a new tab that searches for that inputted text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to grab the inputted text from `textbox`, and open a new tab that displays the search result using `javaScript`. I try to identify the textbox area using `getElementsById`, and grab the inputted text, but it returns undefined. This is the example of what I'm trying to achieve: [example](https://beta.canadasbusinessregistries.ca/search/results?search=%7BExxon%20Mobil%7D&status=Active) .

As of now, my code is returning the following: [this](https://beta.canadasbusinessregistries.ca/search/results?search=%7Bundefined%7D&status=Active) .

```js
function displayPersonOrCompanySearchFields() {
  let person = document.getElementById("person-subject");
  let company = document.getElementById("company-subject");
  let person_states = document.getElementById("person-search-states");
  let company_states = document.getElementById("company-search-states");
  let person_field = document.getElementById("person-search-field");
  let company_field = document.getElementById("company-search-field");

  if (person.checked === true) {
    person_states.style.display = "block";
    person_field.style.display = "block";
    company_states.style.display = "none";
    company_field.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    company_states.style.display = "block";
    company_field.style.display = "block";
    person_states.style.display = "none";
    person_field.style.display = "none";
  }
}

const openCorporateRecordTabs = () => {
  const selectedStateName = document.querySelector('input[name="state-name"]:checked').value;
  const selectedStateUrls = corporaterecordsUrls[selectedStateName];
  selectedStateUrls.forEach(url => window.open(url));
  
}

const companySearch = document.getElementById('company-search-field').value


const corporaterecordsUrls = {
  "federal-level": ["https://www.ic.gc.ca/app/scr/cc/CorporationsCanada/fdrlCrpSrch.html?locale=en_CA"],
  "alberta": [`https://beta.canadasbusinessregistries.ca/search/results?search=%7B${companySearch}%7D&status=Active`],
  "british-columbia": ["https://beta.canadasbusinessregistries.ca/search", "https://www.bccourts.ca/search_judgments.aspx", "https://www.provincialcourt.bc.ca/judgments.php?link=https://www.canlii.org/en/bc/bcpc/"],
  "manitoba": ["https://beta.canadasbusinessregistries.ca/search", "https://companiesonline.gov.mb.ca/"],
  "new-brunswick": ["https://opencorporates.com/", "https://www.pxw2.snb.ca/"],
  "newfoundland-and-labrador": ["https://opencorporates.com/"],
  "nova-scotia": ["https://opencorporates.com/", "https://rjsc.novascotia.ca/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=c123b354ac59e279f1af733e938177f6c5426b4a-1618521288-0-AUxWaXpKmCqfw-_YAUdjtk9Q2Cbm53t55RP0T100hw2a-m7_3UjG_TDZ-Om5CGN9UH6sEha24sil5RRjdqN2Pbasm6aYHl-j71DEpm6LtYb3nGs3QeAcHtzo4c01CRDqUPYwGLqDqIoX7C3PQU6OigVbBEOCD9-gOgBNI8bqNTqV7LEQZ1nKpbwhqOdF7RpW5EfMA4r7fCDWekXEjsNRdUxOOmLCI2oUMhF4PlclYnaRp7FmMr4FrdNCOm9Ch5O2YUogg6qxaT0GmrMVTUz8Y1rbdAH4VKcANUaK6x9HXjzveieEkSd65Dcrn7ezVPTP12S3r43_J9O1eDlIYb961XlVfsHPB2I9K1rG_2c8S-H97YS4gKEpI4M4uu_CqfF0L0l_PamEKWc-pG-yuqhsNPxLIfa9YrVkLUBJs-BHQ_Hhyt9YB6F0YrP8NNs6rTvraw"],
  "ontario": ["https://beta.canadasbusinessregistries.ca/search", "https://www.eservicecorp.ca/"],
  "prince-edward-island": ["https://opencorporates.com/", "https://www.princeedwardisland.ca/en/feature/pei-business-corporate-registry#/home/BusinessAPI/BusinessAPI"],
  "quebec": ["https://beta.canadasbusinessregistries.ca/search", "http://www.registreentreprises.gouv.qc.ca/en/"],
  "saskatchewan": ["https://beta.canadasbusinessregistries.ca/search", "https://corporateregistry.isc.ca/"],
  "northwest-territories": ["https://decisia.lexum.com/nwtcourts-courstno/en/nav.do"],
  "nunavut": ["https://nni.gov.nu.ca/business/search/name"],
  "yukon": ["https://ycor-reey.gov.yk.ca/search"],
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/canada.css"> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/canada.js"></script>
        <title>MESA Canada</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="title">MESA Canada</p>
        </div>
        <div id="company-search-field">
          <input id="company-name" name="company-name" style="background-color: white; margin-left: 1rem; width: 300px; line-height: 5;" placeholder="Insert company name here" />
        </div>
        <div id="person-search-field" name="person-search-field" style="display: none;">
          <input id="first-name" name="first-name" style="background-color: white; margin-left: 1rem; width: 300px; line-height: 5;" placeholder="Insert person first name here" />
          <input id="last-name" name="last-name" style="background-color: white; margin-left: 1rem; width: 300px; line-height: 5;" placeholder="Insert person last name here" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="search-subject" style="margin-left: 1rem;">
          <input type="radio" onclick="displayPersonOrCompanySearchFields()" id="company-subject" name="subject-type" value="company-subject" checked>
          <label for="company-subject">Company</label>
          <input type="radio" onclick="displayPersonOrCompanySearchFields()" id="person-subject" name="subject-type" value="person-subject">
          <label for="person-subject">Person</label>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <!-- WHEN COMPANY IS SELECTED -->
        <div id="company-search-states">
          <div class="states-dropdown-list">
            <form action="" onsubmit="return false;" style="width: 620px; border-right: solid; line-height: 2rem; border-color: darkgreen;">
                <b style="margin-left: 1rem;"><span style="color: darkgreen;">Corporate Records</span> and <span style="color: darkgreen;">Litigation</span> Research</b>
                <div style="border-radius: 25px; width: 30px; height: 30px; flex: auto; margin-top: -2rem; margin-left: 26rem; background-color: black;">
                    <svg style="color: white; background-color: transparent; margin-left: 0.4rem; margin-top: 0.4rem;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-geo" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1a3 3 0 1 0 0 6 3 3 0 0 0 0-6zM4 4a4 4 0 1 1 4.5 3.969V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V7.97A4 4 0 0 1 4 3.999zm2.493 8.574a.5.5 0 0 1-.411.575c-.712.118-1.28.295-1.655.493a1.319 1.319 0 0 0-.37.265.301.301 0 0 0-.057.09V14l.002.008a.147.147 0 0 0 .016.033.617.617 0 0 0 .145.15c.165.13.435.27.813.395.751.25 1.82.414 3.024.414s2.273-.163 3.024-.414c.378-.126.648-.265.813-.395a.619.619 0 0 0 .146-.15.148.148 0 0 0 .015-.033L12 14v-.004a.301.301 0 0 0-.057-.09 1.318 1.318 0 0 0-.37-.264c-.376-.198-.943-.375-1.655-.493a.5.5 0 1 1 .164-.986c.77.127 1.452.328 1.957.594C12.5 13 13 13.4 13 14c0 .426-.26.752-.544.977-.29.228-.68.413-1.116.558-.878.293-2.059.465-3.34.465-1.281 0-2.462-.172-3.34-.465-.436-.145-.826-.33-1.116-.558C3.26 14.752 3 14.426 3 14c0-.599.5-1 .961-1.243.505-.266 1.187-.467 1.957-.594a.5.5 0 0 1 .575.411z" fill="white"></path> 
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <ul class="states-dropdown" style="list-style: none; margin-left: -1.5rem; column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; width: 600px;">
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="federal-level" checked>Federal Level</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="alberta">Alberta<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="british-columbia">British Columbia<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="manitoba">Manitoba<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="new-brunswick">New Brunswick<sup style="font-size: x-small;">*</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="newfoundland-and-labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador<sup style="font-size: x-small;">*</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="nova-scotia">Nova Scotia<sup style="font-size: x-small;">*</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="ontario">Ontario<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="prince-edward-island">Prince Edward Island<sup style="font-size: x-small;">*</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="quebec">Quebec<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="saskatchewan">Saskatchewan<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="northwest-territories">Northwest Territories</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="nunavut">Nunavut</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="yukon">Yukon</label></li>
                </ul>
                <span style="font-size: x-small; position: absolute; padding: 0.5rem;">*OpenCorporates will open</span>
                <br>
                <span style="font-size: x-small; position: absolute; padding: 0.5rem;">**Canada's Business Registries will open</span>
                <br></br>
                <button style="background-color: darkgreen; color: white; border: none; border-radius: 4px; height: 34px; width: 220px; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 1rem;" onclick="openCorporateRecordTabs();">
                    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 -3 20 20" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-left: 2px; background-color: transparent; padding-top: 6px;">
                        <path fill="white" d="M18.109,17.776l-3.082-3.081c-0.059-0.059-0.135-0.077-0.211-0.087c1.373-1.38,2.221-3.28,2.221-5.379c0-4.212-3.414-7.626-7.625-7.626c-4.212,0-7.626,3.414-7.626,7.626s3.414,7.627,7.626,7.627c1.918,0,3.665-0.713,5.004-1.882c0.006,0.085,0.033,0.17,0.098,0.234l3.082,3.081c0.143,0.142,0.371,0.142,0.514,0C18.25,18.148,18.25,17.918,18.109,17.776zM9.412,16.13c-3.811,0-6.9-3.089-6.9-6.9c0-3.81,3.089-6.899,6.9-6.899c3.811,0,6.901,3.09,6.901,6.899C16.312,13.041,13.223,16.13,9.412,16.13z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    Search Corporate Records</button>
                <br></br>
                <button style="background-color: darkgreen; color: white; border: none; border-radius: 4px; height: 34px; width: 210px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: -4.15rem; float: right; margin-right: 5rem;" onclick="openSelectedStateTabs();">
                    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 -3 20 20" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-left: 2px; background-color: transparent; padding-top: 6px;">
                        <path fill="white" d="M18.109,17.776l-3.082-3.081c-0.059-0.059-0.135-0.077-0.211-0.087c1.373-1.38,2.221-3.28,2.221-5.379c0-4.212-3.414-7.626-7.625-7.626c-4.212,0-7.626,3.414-7.626,7.626s3.414,7.627,7.626,7.627c1.918,0,3.665-0.713,5.004-1.882c0.006,0.085,0.033,0.17,0.098,0.234l3.082,3.081c0.143,0.142,0.371,0.142,0.514,0C18.25,18.148,18.25,17.918,18.109,17.776zM9.412,16.13c-3.811,0-6.9-3.089-6.9-6.9c0-3.81,3.089-6.899,6.9-6.899c3.811,0,6.901,3.09,6.901,6.899C16.312,13.041,13.223,16.13,9.412,16.13z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    Search Litigation Cases</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- WHEN PERSON IS SELECTED -->
        <div id="person-search-states" style="display: none;">
          <div class="states-dropdown-list">
            <form action="" onsubmit="return false;" style="width: 620px; border-right: solid; line-height: 2rem; border-color: darkgreen;;">
                <b style="margin-left: 1rem;"><span style="color: darkgreen;">Corporate Affiliations</span> and <span style="color: darkgreen;">Litigation</span> Research</b>
                <div style="border-radius: 25px; width: 30px; height: 30px; flex: auto; margin-top: -2rem; margin-left: 28rem; background-color: black;">
                    <svg style="color: white; background-color: transparent; margin-left: 0.4rem; margin-top: 0.4rem;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-geo" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1a3 3 0 1 0 0 6 3 3 0 0 0 0-6zM4 4a4 4 0 1 1 4.5 3.969V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V7.97A4 4 0 0 1 4 3.999zm2.493 8.574a.5.5 0 0 1-.411.575c-.712.118-1.28.295-1.655.493a1.319 1.319 0 0 0-.37.265.301.301 0 0 0-.057.09V14l.002.008a.147.147 0 0 0 .016.033.617.617 0 0 0 .145.15c.165.13.435.27.813.395.751.25 1.82.414 3.024.414s2.273-.163 3.024-.414c.378-.126.648-.265.813-.395a.619.619 0 0 0 .146-.15.148.148 0 0 0 .015-.033L12 14v-.004a.301.301 0 0 0-.057-.09 1.318 1.318 0 0 0-.37-.264c-.376-.198-.943-.375-1.655-.493a.5.5 0 1 1 .164-.986c.77.127 1.452.328 1.957.594C12.5 13 13 13.4 13 14c0 .426-.26.752-.544.977-.29.228-.68.413-1.116.558-.878.293-2.059.465-3.34.465-1.281 0-2.462-.172-3.34-.465-.436-.145-.826-.33-1.116-.558C3.26 14.752 3 14.426 3 14c0-.599.5-1 .961-1.243.505-.266 1.187-.467 1.957-.594a.5.5 0 0 1 .575.411z" fill="white"></path> 
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <ul class="states-dropdown" id="provinces-list" style="list-style: none; margin-left: -1.5rem; column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; width: 600px;">
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="federal-level" checked>Federal Level</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="alberta">Alberta<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="british-columbia">British Columbia<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="manitoba">Manitoba<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="new-brunswick">New Brunswick<sup style="font-size: x-small;">*</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="newfoundland-and-labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador<sup style="font-size: x-small;">*</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="nova-scotia">Nova Scotia<sup style="font-size: x-small;">*</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="ontario">Ontario<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="prince-edward-island">Prince Edward Island<sup style="font-size: x-small;">*</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="quebec">Quebec<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="saskatchewan">Saskatchewan<sup style="font-size: x-small;">**</sup></label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="northwest-territories">Northwest Territories</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="nunavut">Nunavut</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state-name" class="state" value="yukon">Yukon</label></li>
                </ul>
                <span style="font-size: x-small; position: absolute; padding: 0.5rem;">*OpenCorporates will open</span>
                <br>
                <span style="font-size: x-small; position: absolute; padding: 0.5rem;">**Canada's Business Registries will open</span>
                <br></br>
                <button style="background-color: darkgreen; color: white; border: none; border-radius: 4px; height: 34px; width: 220px; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 1rem;" onclick="openCorporateRecordTabs();">
                    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 -3 20 20" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-left: 2px; background-color: transparent; padding-top: 6px;">
                        <path fill="white" d="M18.109,17.776l-3.082-3.081c-0.059-0.059-0.135-0.077-0.211-0.087c1.373-1.38,2.221-3.28,2.221-5.379c0-4.212-3.414-7.626-7.625-7.626c-4.212,0-7.626,3.414-7.626,7.626s3.414,7.627,7.626,7.627c1.918,0,3.665-0.713,5.004-1.882c0.006,0.085,0.033,0.17,0.098,0.234l3.082,3.081c0.143,0.142,0.371,0.142,0.514,0C18.25,18.148,18.25,17.918,18.109,17.776zM9.412,16.13c-3.811,0-6.9-3.089-6.9-6.9c0-3.81,3.089-6.899,6.9-6.899c3.811,0,6.901,3.09,6.901,6.899C16.312,13.041,13.223,16.13,9.412,16.13z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    Search Corporate Records</button>
                <br></br>
                <button style="background-color: darkgreen; color: white; border: none; border-radius: 4px; height: 34px; width: 210px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: -4.15rem; float: right; margin-right: 5rem;" onclick="openSelectedStateTabs();">
                    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 -3 20 20" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-left: 2px; background-color: transparent; padding-top: 6px;">
                        <path fill="white" d="M18.109,17.776l-3.082-3.081c-0.059-0.059-0.135-0.077-0.211-0.087c1.373-1.38,2.221-3.28,2.221-5.379c0-4.212-3.414-7.626-7.625-7.626c-4.212,0-7.626,3.414-7.626,7.626s3.414,7.627,7.626,7.627c1.918,0,3.665-0.713,5.004-1.882c0.006,0.085,0.033,0.17,0.098,0.234l3.082,3.081c0.143,0.142,0.371,0.142,0.514,0C18.25,18.148,18.25,17.918,18.109,17.776zM9.412,16.13c-3.811,0-6.9-3.089-6.9-6.9c0-3.81,3.089-6.899,6.9-6.899c3.811,0,6.901,3.09,6.901,6.899C16.312,13.041,13.223,16.13,9.412,16.13z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    Search Litigation Cases</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Reduce the code to the absolute minimum required to demonstrate the issue. Likely 95% of the OP code is superfluous. You should also supply sample input with expected output and actual output, plus any errors.

Comment: I've just voted to close, as I feel the question needs "details, or clarity" (though "needs more focus" was a very close second). Please, reduce as much as you can (and  - even if you're using a js-in-css framework  - remove the styling from inline `style` attributes to a stylesheet (even an inline `<style>` element in the document would reduce some of the noise that we're trying to look through). Further to that, there's invalid HTML `</br>` doesn't exist, a `<br>` is a void element (doesn't need to be closed), you're linking - and not using - jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are selecting the div around the input not the input itself.

```
const companySearch = document.getElementById('company-name')
```

should be your selector.
Then you must also make sure you read the value after the value has been set, not before. As you do not show the code that actually triggers the action I cannot help with the last part